# Error while log in authentication in Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js, backend

I have created an API for LogIn authentication. I have used Sequelize ORM for Mysql Database. Given below is an image of my *users* model which i have imported in my authentication code for login.

[Models/users image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4TxP.png)

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
    const Tutorial = sequelize.define("users", {
        age: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER },
        name: { type: Sequelize.STRING },
        email: { type: Sequelize.STRING },
        password: { type: Sequelize.STRING }
    });
    return Tutorial
};
```

Here below is the code for log in authentication. I have used **findOne** function for getting the email & password and i have used **.then** which is a promise function that returns the response.

```
var users = require('./models/users');

app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    var email = req.body.email;
    var password = req.body.password;
    users.findOne({ email: email, password: password })
        .then(users => {

            if (users == null) {
                res.status(404).json({
                    message: 'Auth Failed'
                })

            }
            else {
                res.status(200).json({
                    message: 'Logg In succesfull'
                })
            }
        })
})
```

But when i hit the API, it shows error

```
TypeError: users.findOne is not a function
    at D:\Node\Task\server.js:39:11
```

Please help me fix it.

Comment: [No images of code](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) please

Comment: Model of users

module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
    const Tutorial = sequelize.define("users", {
        age: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER
        },
        name: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        email: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        password: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
    });
    return Tutorial
};

Comment: My guess is, you are exporting a function that returns a model, so, you should execute this function : `var users = require('./models/users')();`. Or, export your model directly : `module.exports = sequelize.define("users", ...`

Comment: this will cause error with all other function of my code where i have implemented CRUD

Comment: do you think, the issue is with model import?

Answer (score 0):

> module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {

Because your function accepts 2 parameters, you'll have to pass the values as well in the `require` to get it working.

```
const sequel = require('sequelize');
const DataTypes = sequel.DataTypes;
const sequelizeInstance = new sequel(...) // import your sequelize config 

var users = require('./models/users')(sequelizeInstance, DataTypes);
```

Comment: i have used this for reference.
https://www.bezkoder.com/node-js-express-sequelize-mysql/
please see to this.

Comment: But why import them in the main file, then pass them to `require`, instead of importing them directly in the required file? It would avoid this "export a function then call it and pass it imported stuff" mess, don't you think?

Comment: yes absolutely @JeremyThille thats how it should be. But the crux here is to assist him in getting it working. if the question was oriented towards a suggestion, then I'd suggest the same thing!

Comment: Sid , brother share with me any way to connect with you. Discord, Twitter, any Please

Comment: always welcome. https://meet.google.com/skg-uocd-jfa

Comment: Hi @sid i seek your help with performing role based permission.

Comment: where are u stuck

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about Sequelize, but inspired by @sid's answer, I guess something like this is cleaner than importing `Sequelize` in the main file, then pass it to the imported file... Just import your dependencies in each file.

models/users :

```
    const sequel = require('sequelize');
    const DataTypes = sequel.DataTypes;
    const sequelizeInstance = new sequel(...) // import your sequelize config 
    
    module.exports = sequelize.define("users", {
            age: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER },
            name: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
            email: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
            password: { type: DataTypes.STRING }
    })
```

Then simply import it :

```
const users = require('./models/users');
users.findOne({ email, password })
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is still unanswered it could be because of two reasons. Either you're importing the model wrong, or its because you're calling the query without it being async (As I've had similar issues with this as a cause):

```
const { users } = require('./models')

async app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    try {
        const email = req.body.email
        const password = req.body.password

        const user = await users.findOne({
            where: {
                email: email,
                password: password // Remove this if you have a verify password func
            }
        })

        if (!user) {
            res.status(403).send({
                error: "Password or email is wrong"
            })
        }

        // You should really encrypt the passwords and have a compare/verify function instead
        // Example
        if (!bcrypy.compareSync(password, user.password)) {
            res.status(403).send({
                error: "Password or email is wrong"
            })
        }

        res.staus(200).send(user) // Save user to store/cache on client
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        res.status(500).send({
            error: "Error occured during login"
        })
    }
})
```

Once you have more of your frontend setup, you should send the user back to the client and then store it in client side cache or smth, so you don't need to query the server for logged in user data everytime.